# Can't run method asynchronously in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, methods, mappoint

I have the following code:

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
private delegate void LoadMapPointRegion();

private LoadMapPointRegion lmprd;
private MapPoint.Application mpApp;
private MapPoint.Map mpMap;
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    lmprd = new LoadMapPointRegion(mpControl_LoadRegion);
    lmprd.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(mpControl_RegionLoaded), null);
}

private void mpControl_LoadRegion()
{
    mpControl.NewMap(MapPoint.GeoMapRegion.geoMapNorthAmerica);
    mpMap = mpControl.ActiveMap;
    mpApp = mpMap.Application;
}

private void mpControl_RegionLoaded(IAsyncResult iar)
{
    MessageBox.Show("MapPoint loaded async: " + iar.CompletedSynchronously.ToString());
}
}
```

This should load form and enable interactions with it while `mpControl_LoadRegion` is running.
It takes from 5 to 10 seconds to load map point regions thus why I am doing it asynchronously.

However `iar.CompletedSynchronously` is always false.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [CompletedSynchronously Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.completedsynchronously.aspx) indicates whether the operation was completed synchronously rather than asynchronously. It doesn't mean that the operation wasn't completed at all.

Comment: +1 Exactly; in other words - you did it Asynchronously, which means *not* synchronously, so it's false.

Comment: Understood, I miss-looked the word Synchronously as Asynchronously